# Reloading UIScrollView content causes auto layout errors

Tags: swift2

I have an up that has 2 uiscrollviews. 1 for vertical and another for horizontal content.

In my viewwillappear function I fetch the data from an API to populate these 2 views. I also have a bool to determine if the data needs to be re-fetched based on users actions from within the app. Initially this bool is set to true (fetch data) and once the information is fetched successfully I set this to false (do not fetch). If a user performs some action that requires a re-fetch, I set the bool back to true so the next time they load the view I get the new data.

The issue I am having is that the horizontal uiscrollview has a dynamic number of pages and if I need to re-fetch (after the first time the view is loaded) all my constraints fail and I am unable to see the new data. The first time the view loads everything works perfectly, it's only if I need to re-fetch is when the issue occurs.

I have tried calling

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

on the superview and on the uiscrollview but that does nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: Use this view.setNeedsLayout() and
 view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: This didn't do anything. I already have these in the viewDidLoad. Moving them to viewWillAppear caused more issues.

Comment: please edit the question with more code

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out. The structure of the scroll views were slightly incorrect in that I did not put the contents inside a separate container UIView.